# How to exclude results from my resultset based on a different row?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have one table t1 with clientdivisionid, planid, memberid and values are

154 | 722 | 27510,
154 | 722 | 22222,
154 | 725 | 27510

I need to pull only members where planID = 722 for members who are not part of plan 725.

So result should be
 154| 722 | 22222

here is my SQL

```
Select memberid,planid 
from t1 
group by memberid,planid
 having ((planid = 722) and (planid <> 725 ))
```

When I use where or having statement it still pulls in member id 27510.

Comment: Show your current SQL Statement. We can't help you debug code we can't see. Also,l what is the data type of the field?

Comment: select memberid,planid from t1 group by memberid,planid having ((planid = 722) and (planid <> 725 ));

Comment: You don't have a where clause in your SQL. How do you expect it to filter anything?

Comment: sorry i am new to this post .I just updated having clause

Comment: If you want planid=722 then what is the point of specifying planid<>725 Those criteria are redundant

Comment: And why would the result be the second line but not the first?

Comment: because i dont want to display memberid that has planid 722 and 725 . I want to only pull only and only member that has planid = 722

Comment: Right. So PlanID=722 only returns 722. Your query is kind of like saying ONLY bring be bananas, also don't bring me apples.

Comment: I thought memberid was the first column. but that makes sense

Comment: So let me get this straight. You want to know all members who have plan ID 722, but don't also have planID 725?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t1.clientdivisionid,
    t1.planid,
    t1.memberid
FROM
    t1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT memberid
        FROM t1
        WHERE planid = 725
    ) AS subExclude
    ON t1.memberid = subExclude.memberid
WHERE
        t1.planid = 722
    AND subExclude.memberid Is Null;
```

If you want to alter the selection to `planid = 722` and not 725 and not 728 and not 727, change the `WHERE` clause in the subquery to this:

```
WHERE planid IN (725, 728, 727)
```

Comment: OK, I just finished changing it to use only one subquery instead of two.  I think it should still work, but let me know if I broke it.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
SELECT memberid,planid
FROM tab1 t1
WHERE planid = 722
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tab1 t2
    WHERE t1.memberid = t2.memberid AND t2.planid = 725
    )
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8609f/3)</kbd>

EDIT:

If you only want to select the ones that have planid = 722, and no other planid you can put planid <> 722 in the subquery:

```
SELECT memberid, planid
FROM tab1 t1
WHERE planid = 722
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tab1 t2
    WHERE t1.memberid = t2.memberid AND t2.planid != 722
    )
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/743c7/3)</kbd>

This can be quite efficient because it stops looking as soon as it finds one value in the subquery that has planid != 722.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
Select memberid,planid 
from t1 
where (PlanID=722) and not memberid in(SELECT MemberID 
                                       FROM t1 
                                       WHERE planid=725)
group by memberid,planid
```

If you want members with PlanID 722 and NO others, do this

```
 Select memberid,planid 
    from t1 
    where (PlanID=722) and not memberid in(SELECT MemberID 
                                           FROM t1 
                                           WHERE planid<>725)
    group by memberid,planid
```

alternatively (might perform a little better)

```
 Select memberid,planid 
    from t1 
    where (PlanID=722) and not exists(SELECT MemberID 
                                           FROM t1 
                                           WHERE planid<>725)
    group by memberid,planid
```

Comment: well this pulls in memberid 27510 and since this member is also in plan id 725. I need to pull only and only member that has elected plan 722

Comment: Hang on. Editing my answer now. Your question was extremely confusingly worded.

Comment: This did work. I have one more question to this . If i want to only and only show members in planid 722 and not 725 and not 728 and not 727 then where would i add this other planid ?

Comment: Specifically 725,727 and 728 or are you saying you only want members with 725 and NO other plans?

Comment: i want only members with planid 722 and not any other plans. Other planid is 725,727,728

Comment: See my edit to my answer. It doesn't make sense to hard code the other values unless you want to edit this query every time your DB changes.